# How to determine cause of "ValueError: Element cannot be located in parent view"? - Odoo 10.0e Enterprise

Tags: inheritance, odoo-10, valueerror

I recently made the mistake of upgrading Base module while trying to customize reports by inheriting through a custom module. I'm working through customizations that were performed in developer mode in the UI. I was able to correct the previous customizations that were stored in ir_ui_view. However, I am getting an error when trying to print invoices to PDF and I haven't been able to find the cause. There is some connection that I haven't found yet and I'm using it as an opportunity to understand report inheritance.

The error is:

```
ValueError: Element '<xpath expr="//div/[@name='invoice_address']">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `report_invoice_document_inherit_sale`
[view_id: 1119, xml_id: sale.report_invoice_document_inherit_sale, model: n/a, parent_id: 735]

load could not load template
Template: account.report_invoice_document
```

Here is the inherit from ir_ui_view:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
        <xpath expr="//div[@name='invoice_address']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="groups">!sale.group_delivery_invoice_address</attribute>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//div[@name='invoice_address']" position="before">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-7" groups="sale.group_delivery_invoice_address">
                <strong t-if="o.partner_shipping_id == o.partner_id">Invoicing and shipping address:</strong>
                <strong t-if="o.partner_shipping_id != o.partner_id">Invoicing address:</strong>
                <div t-field="o.partner_id" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: True}"/>
                 <span t-if="o.partner_id.vat">TIN: <span t-field="o.partner_id.vat"/></span>
                <div t-if="o.partner_shipping_id != o.partner_id" class="mt8">
                    <strong>Shipping address:</strong>
                    <div t-field="o.partner_shipping_id" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: True}"/>
                    <span t-if="o.partner_id.vat">TIN: <span t-field="o.partner_id.vat"/></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xpath>
   </data>
```

And here is the parent file `account\reports\report_invoice.xml` which contains template `'report_invoice_document'`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<data>
<template id="report_invoice_document">
    <t t-call="report.external_layout">
        <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context({'lang':o.partner_id.lang})" />
        <div class="page">
            <div class="row">
                <div name="invoice_address" class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-7">
                    <address t-field="o.partner_id"
                    t-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name"], "no_marker": True}' />
                    <span t-if="o.partner_id.vat">TIN: <span t-field="o.partner_id.vat"/></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h2>
                <span t-if="o.type == 'out_invoice' and (o.state == 'open' or o.state == 'paid')">Invoice</span>
                <span t-if="o.type == 'out_invoice' and o.state == 'proforma2'">PRO-FORMA</span>
                <span t-if="o.type == 'out_invoice' and o.state == 'draft'">Draft Invoice</span>
                <span t-if="o.type == 'out_invoice' and o.state == 'cancel'">Cancelled Invoice</span>
                <span t-if="o.type == 'out_refund'">Refund</span>
                <span t-if="o.type == 'in_refund'">Vendor Refund</span>
                <span t-if="o.type == 'in_invoice'">Vendor Bill</span>
                <span t-field="o.number"/>
            </h2>

            <div class="row mt32 mb32">
                <div class="col-xs-2" t-if="o.name">
                    <strong>Description:</strong>
                    <p t-field="o.name"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" t-if="o.date_invoice">
                    <strong>Invoice Date:</strong>
                    <p t-field="o.date_invoice"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" t-if="o.date_due and o.type == 'out_invoice' and (o.state == 'open' or o.state == 'paid')">
                    <strong>Due Date:</strong>
                    <p t-field="o.date_due"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" t-if="o.origin">
                    <strong>Source:</strong>
                    <p t-field="o.origin"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" t-if="o.partner_id.ref">
                    <strong>Customer Code:</strong>
                    <p t-field="o.partner_id.ref"/>
                </div>
                <div name="reference" class="col-xs-2" t-if="o.reference and o.type == 'in_invoice'">
                    <strong>Reference:</strong>
                    <p t-field="o.reference"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Is there a discount on at least one line? -->
            <t t-set="display_discount" t-value="any([l.discount for l in o.invoice_line_ids])"/>

            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th class="hidden">Source Document</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Quantity</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Unit Price</th>
                        <th t-if="display_discount" class="text-right" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line">Disc.(%)</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Taxes</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Tax Excluded Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="invoice_tbody">
                    <tr t-foreach="o.invoice_line_ids" t-as="l">
                        <td><span t-field="l.name"/></td>
                        <td class="hidden"><span t-field="l.origin"/></td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <span t-field="l.quantity"/>
                            <span t-field="l.uom_id"  groups="product.group_uom"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <span t-field="l.price_unit"/>
                        </td>
                        <td t-if="display_discount" class="text-right" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line">
                            <span t-field="l.discount"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <span t-esc="', '.join(map(lambda x: (x.description or x.name), l.invoice_line_tax_ids))"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <span t-field="l.price_subtotal" 
                             t-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": o.currency_id}'/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>



            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <tr class="border-black">
                            <td><strong>Subtotal</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="o.amount_untaxed" options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": o.currency_id}'/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <t t-foreach="o._get_tax_amount_by_group()" t-as="amount_by_group">
                            <tr>
                                <td><span t-esc="amount_by_group[0]"/></td>
                                <td class="text-right">
                                    <span t-esc="amount_by_group[1]"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </t>
                        <tr class="border-black">
                            <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                 <span t-field="o.amount_total" t-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": o.currency_id}'/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <p t-if="o.comment">
                <strong>Comment:</strong>
                <span t-field="o.comment"/>
            </p>
            <p t-if="o.payment_term_id">
                <span t-field="o.payment_term_id.note"/>
            </p>
            <p t-if="o.fiscal_position_id.note">
                <strong>Fiscal Position Remark:</strong>
                <span t-field="o.fiscal_position_id.note"/>
            </p>
         </div>
    </t>
</template>

<template id="report_invoice">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="account.report_invoice_document" t-lang="o.partner_id.lang"/>
       </t>
    </t>
</template>

<template id="account_invoice_report_duplicate" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document" primary="True">
    <xpath expr="//h2" position="replace">
        <h2>
            <span>Duplicate</span>
            <span t-field="o.number"/>
        </h2>
    </xpath>
</template>

<template id="account_invoice_report_duplicate_main">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="account.account_invoice_report_duplicate" t-lang="o.partner_id.lang"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
</data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: I'm realizing my initial explanation is gibberish. Previously, I performed all customizations to views and reports through the settings screen in developer mode. I am learning to develop custom modules to extend Odoo so that my changes are not lost upon upgrade. In the process of doing this I upgraded Base module, which removed my previous customizations from ir_ui_view. I was able to update that table with the previous values, but I am receiving the above error when printing invoices to PDF, and I think the error is related, but I am unable to determine the cause.

Comment: Are you able to reduce this further? Try to find a reproducible case with the least code.

Comment: The problem is that I think this is the unaltered invoice report, so I'm trying to piece together why it is causing an error. I wouldn't know where to begin reducing the code as I want the report as is.

Comment: Being able to reduce code to a minimum reproduction case is a critical development skill and helps _a lot_ when asking unusual questions like this one. You'll have to make some educated guesses and meet in the middle here, unless an odoo expert comes along and knows what's going on :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Litty for the help. I found that I had updated the arch_db field of ir_ui_view for id 735 (account.report_invoice_document) with the wrong values, so the dependent documents were trying to inherit completely unrelated XML.

Should I just delete the question?